# WPF Changing fill colour of ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm trying to make 8 circles which all have different fill colours and all have different blinking speeds. So far I have been able to make them blink at different speeds, but I'm having trouble with making them all have different colours. My code so far:

```
    private void Appear(Ellipse element, double duration, Brush colour)
    {
        element.Fill = colour;
        DoubleAnimation db = new DoubleAnimation();
        db.From = 0.0;
        db.To = 1.0;
        db.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));
        db.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        element.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.OpacityProperty, db);
    }

    private Brush SetEllipseColour(Ellipse element)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int red = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        int green = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        int blue = rnd.Next(0, 255);

        Brush fillColour = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)red, (byte)green, (byte)blue));
        return fillColour;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<Ellipse> elements = new List<Ellipse>();
        elements.Add(Circle1);
        elements.Add(Circle2);
        elements.Add(Circle3);
        elements.Add(Circle4);
        elements.Add(Circle5);
        elements.Add(Circle6);
        elements.Add(Circle7);
        elements.Add(Circle8);

        Random rnd = new Random();

        foreach (Ellipse element in elements)
        {
            int r = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            double duration = (Double)r / 10;
            Appear(element, duration, SetEllipseColour(element));
        }
    }
```

And my WPF:

```
<Canvas Margin="10">
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle1"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"/>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle2"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"
                Margin="120,0,0,0"/>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle3"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"
                Margin="240,0,0,0"/>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle4"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"
                Margin="360,0,0,0"/>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle5"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"
                Margin="0,120,0,0"/>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle6"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"
                Margin="120,120,0,0"/>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle7"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"
                Margin="240,120,0,0"/>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="Circle8"
                Fill="Black"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"
                Margin="360,120,0,0"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Start" Width="80" Height="20" Margin="0,200,0,0" Click="button1_Click"/>
```

Note: I know I can compress / change my code to make it neater or better, but for now I just want to get the colours working.

So currently the code I have changes the fill colour of **all** Ellipse elements, but I want to change it to just affect each Circle. How would I go about doing this?

**Edit:**
For those who are confused what Im trying to ask, I do not know how to individually change the fill colour of every Circle.

Comment: _"I'm having trouble with making them all have different colours"_ -- please be more specific. What kind of trouble, _exactly_. What have you tried in terms of changing the code you show above, so that it instead handles each ellipse separately? Do you _really_ need eight different ellipses in your code to illustrate the issue? Please edit your post so it includes just a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates your question, and a detailed, precise explanation of what specific issue you have.

Comment: *"I don't know how to individually change the fill colour of every Circle"* - how do you want to achieve this? Through code-behind or through the Xaml? *When* do you want this to occur? Your question is still very unclear

Answer (score 3):

Set the instance of the `Random` class at the class level, check the below example, by clicking on the the `Button` that says *Blink Em!* the animation is triggered.

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Blink.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Blink"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="BlinkEm" Content="Blink Em!" Height="30" Click="BlinkEm_Click"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Container" Orientation="Horizontal" Loaded="Container_Loaded" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind

```
namespace Blink
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Random random = new Random();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Ellipse> CreateCircles(int count)
        {
            List<Ellipse> circles = new List<Ellipse>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var circle = new Ellipse
                {
                    Height = 100,
                    Width = 100,
                    Margin = new Thickness(10),
                    Fill = Brushes.SkyBlue
                };

                circles.Add(circle);
            }

            return circles;
        }

        public void AddCircles()
        {
            var circles = this.CreateCircles(8);
            foreach (var circle in circles)
            {
                Container.Children.Add(circle);
            }
        }

        private void Container_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddCircles();
        }

        private void BlinkEm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Ellipse circle in Container.Children)
            {
                circle.Fill = GetRandomColor();
                circle.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.OpacityProperty, GetBlinkAnimation());
            }
        }

        public Brush GetRandomColor()
        {
            var red = Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 255));
            var green = Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 255));
            var blue = Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 255));

            return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(red, green, blue));
        }

        public DoubleAnimation GetBlinkAnimation()
        {
            var duration = random.NextDouble();
            var animation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = 0.0,
                To = 1.0,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration)),
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
            };

            return animation;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake here is that the Random object is being recreated every time. Try putting that into a field and initializing it once, or by sending it as a parameter to your SetEllipseColor method.

Due to random number generators not actually being random, they derive their "initial" random values from a seed value, often the current time. This means if you create a bunch of new Random instances in a very short time, they are likely to end up with the same seed and thus the same value.

(In more general terms, "Appear" and "SetEllipseColor" aren't very good method names. The former is vague and the latter doesn't actually describe what that method is doing.)

Comment: What do you mean "Try putting that into a field and initializing it once"? Sorry, Im fairly new to C# and WPF

Comment: A field on your class - sort of a variable, but scoped to your whole object (one instance of it, mind) instead of just a method. You might try this:
`private readonly Random _random = new Random();`

Comment: so what has that got to do with the colour changing?

Comment: You are correct that the OP needs to fix their `Random` object initialization, to use a single shared object across all method calls. You are _incorrect_ in assuming this has anything to do with the problem at hand. There's no code in the example that shows any attempt to treat each ellipse individually, so the bug with the `Random` object is moot.

Comment: @PeterDuniho
Incorrect. He's looping them at the end of the button click handler.

Comment: _"He's looping them at the end of the button click handler"_ -- which handles the objects _together_, not _individually_, i.e. changing the color of _all_ ellipses at the same time. Your observation merely supports exactly what I wrote. But, whatever...you want to keep your answer here even though it has nothing to do with the problem at hand, that's your prerogative.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What he's doing is (kinda) reasonable, it's not intuitive that the PRNG behaves the way it does unless you're already aware. 

My answer is relevant, otherwise you can explain exactly how it isn't.